# Create .EAR with Spring Boot application to deploy in websphere 9.0.0.7

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, udeploy

I have developed a Spring Boot application with jpa. First I used in built tomcat server, its working fine. Now I want it to deploy in websphere 9.0.0.7.
I have tried to deploy WAR into websphere by using deploy. I am getting following error

```
Username: Password:  WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node dmgr using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
WASX7303I: The following options are passed to the scripting environment and are available as arguments that are stored in the argv variable: 
"[/app/dmgr/xxx/deploy.py, /app/wam/test/testa.xml, /opt/app/ibm-ucd/agent/var/work/xxx/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]"

War files must have a context-root specified in the deployment xml
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/app/dmgr/xxxxx//deploy.py"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException:
 exception from Jython:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 37, in <module>
  File "/app/dmgr/xxxx/was/deploy.py", line 129, in deploy
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

From above exception, I have added `server.servlet.context-path=/test`, but there is no use, same issue coming again.

In my application I don't have any sub modules any thing. What are the changes I need to do , to deploy in websphere ? As I need to package as **.ear** or I need to add **ibm....web.xml** which adds some data related context.I don't want to any manual packaging from war to ear

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: First, I'd strongly recommend to install it via web administrative console, and ensure that it installs and run correctly. Then you can play with the udeploy.

Comment: It's got resolved by following this example https://github.com/guilu/spring-boot-ear-skinny-war. Now the issue is Websphere 9.0.07 using default JPA provided by WAS.Due to this unable to create  entitymanager object. How to exclude that old JPA jar or load latest JPA versions provided by in my WAR file.

Comment: I could not get this working by following [link](http://github.com/guilu/spring-boot-ear-skinny-war). Can someone help me find a perfect guide for including multiple WAR files in EAR and get it running in Websphere.